# Core Data invalid number of rows error without inserting/removing rows

Tags: core-data, uitableview

I'm modifying (but not adding or removing) objects in a Core Data store upon selection of a UITableViewCell. However, whenever I do so, I get the following error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of 
NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: 
invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section 
after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before 
the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 
inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that 
section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

...except that I've not inserted or deleted any new rows, I've just modified a property on an existing object which backs up the row. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you implement all FRC delegate methods "controllerWillChangeContent", "didChangeObject" and "controllerDidChangeContent"? Is is the standard boilerplate code as in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol Reference?

Comment: Yep. That's all in there - standard boilerplate from the Master/Detail View + Core Data project template.

Comment: Strange. - The error message claims that "insertRows..." has been called for one row, but the number of objects in the section has not changed.

Comment: Right - tell me about it. Very strange.